# phpmyadmin configuration program doesn't start after abort (LEMP, Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

As I was following on this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-server, halfway I entered a wrong option. That is why I aborted the installation proces, removed phpmyadmin with the commands below and tried to restart the installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now, when I enter the following commands as to restart the installation proces, no program is started that takes me to the next step, which is:

> During the installation process, you will be prompted to choose the
> web server (either Apache or Lighthttp) to configure. Because we are
> using Nginx as web server, we shouldn’t make a choice here. Press tab
> and then OK to advance to the next step.
>
> Next, you’ll be prompted whether to use dbconfig-common for
> configuring the application database. Select Yes. This will set up the
> internal database and administrative user for phpMyAdmin. You will be
> asked to define a new password for the phpmyadmin MySQL user. You can
> also leave it blank and let phpMyAdmin randomly create a password.

Any advice on how I can restart the installation procedure? I am installing on Ubuntu 20.04 with a LEMP-stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already done `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, then to be prompted again for the configuration options you can run `dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`. dpkg-reconfigure runs the same post-install configuration scripts, and the -plow sets the priority to the lowest setting, so you'll be asked about every available configuration option (higher settings will sometimes guess at what's best for your system, which is helpful for instance in an automated installation situation).

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It worked for me after this successive line of coding: sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin sudo apt-get autoremove dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin sudo apt update sudo apt install phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer that was provided by Isaac Bennetch, I want to offer a different solution here. At Digital Ocean, there is the option to access the server via an internal console. This console did prompt me with the configuration options. So, using a different console is not the neatest option, but it works :)